# react loading SVG as a module using webpack

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, webpacker

I'm trying to get my webpack to filter svg imports and generate react components with the files.

this is my  webpacker configuration:

```
//config/webpack/development.js
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const environment = require("./environment");
const svg_react_loader = require("./custom/svg-react-loader");

module.exports = merge(environment.toWebpackConfig(), svg_react_loader);

//config/webpack/custom/svg-react-loader
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "react-svg-loader",
            options: {
              jsx: true // true outputs JSX tags
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I'm importing the svg file in my component as follows:

```
import ProjectLogo from "./images/project.svg";
```

the error I'm getting in the browser console is:

```
react-dom.development.js?cada:6050 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/packs/bundles/Project/components/LogoPage/images/project-f15c8edd029d0f795dd71e3e39079866.svg') is not a valid name.
    at createElement (webpack-internal:///250:6050:36)
    at createInstance (webpack-internal:///250:16908:22)
    at completeWork (webpack-internal:///250:10916:31)
    at completeUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///250:12481:18)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///250:12580:14)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///250:12682:28)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (webpack-internal:///250:1299:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (webpack-internal:///250:1338:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (webpack-internal:///250:1195:27)
    at performWork (webpack-internal:///250:12800:7)
createElement @ react-dom.development.js?cada:6050
createInstance @ react-dom.development.js?cada:16908
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js?cada:10916
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?cada:12481
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?cada:12580
workLoop @ react-dom.development.js?cada:12682
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js?cada:1299
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js?cada:1338
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js?cada:1195
performWork @ react-dom.development.js?cada:12800
scheduleUpdateImpl @ react-dom.development.js?cada:13185
scheduleUpdate @ react-dom.development.js?cada:13124
scheduleTopLevelUpdate @ react-dom.development.js?cada:13395
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js?cada:13425
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js?cada:17105
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js?cada:13256
renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js?cada:17104
render @ react-dom.development.js?cada:17129
render @ clientStartup.js?eb41:154
forEach @ clientStartup.js?eb41:64
forEachComponent @ clientStartup.js?eb41:76
reactOnRailsPageLoaded @ clientStartup.js?eb41:177
(anonymous) @ clientStartup.js?eb41:232
```

Comment: do you need to load it like a file? I find its much easier to just make a component out of your svg `Logo = props => <svg...</svg>`

Comment: would you just add the svg's xml data inside the <svg> tag?

Comment: here's an example https://github.com/torontojs/torontojs.com/blob/master/src/components/svg/Logo.js

Comment: While this would certainly solve the problem, I don't really like placing something this hard to read within a js file, I don't find it to be good practice.

Comment: not good practice? strange point of view. never heard anything like that. you can just treat it like an npm module where the code you're importing is minified and significantly hard to read

Comment: yep, but it's not an npm module, it's code you maintain, and you need to copy paste from your svg editor when you change it. quite harder to maintain, imo.